# Table nested in a rowspan table cell doesn't fill cell height in all browsers

Tags: html, css

[rendering and code in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPqcX.jpg)

I cannot figure out why the nested table (marked red) is not occupying the full height of the outer (marked green) table cell (that spans over 8 rows).
This used to work, but newer browsers don't let the nested table occupy the full height of the outer table cell. IE11 with compatibility view still shows this occupying the full height, all others don't. What do I need to change in the code? Adding height="100%" to the table doesn't help.

Code:

```
    <tr>
      <td class="NameColumnCaption" valign="top" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" style="height: 19px;">11:00</td>
      <td class="weekdetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" rowspan="8" colspan="10" style="cursor:pointer" ondblclick="modifyMeeting(&quot;212&amp;dispUser=Janice%20Elland&amp;globObjID=&quot;, 9);" onclick="detailview(&quot;oneweek.asp?Q=Janice%20Elland&amp;D=-4&quot;);hN(33);" onmousemove="sN(33)" onmouseout="hN(33)">
        <table class="tdnor" width="100%" id="tbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="white">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="5" bgcolor="#99ccff" style="height: 19px;"><img src="b1.gif" width="2px" height="10px" border="0"></td>
              <td class="WeekDetails" valign="top" style="height: 19px;">
                <font color="#0000cc">11:15-15:15</font><br>
                <font color="#000000">Supplier Meeting</font> (Lancashire)Janice Elland<br>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="WeekDetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" colspan="10" onmousemove="sN(0)" onmouseout="hN(0)" onclick="Meeting2(&quot;&amp;D=-2&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;Janice%20Elland&quot;);" style="height: 19px;"></td>
      <td valign="top" class="WeekDetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" colspan="10" onmousemove="sN(0)" onmouseout="hN(0)" onclick="Meeting2(&quot;&amp;D=-1&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;Janice%20Elland&quot;);" style="height: 19px;"></td>
      <td valign="top" class="WeekDetails" bgcolor="#95cc68" colspan="10" onmousemove="sN(0)" onmouseout="hN(0)" onclick="Meeting2(&quot;&amp;D=0&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;Janice%20Elland&quot;);" style="height: 19px;"></td>
      <td class="NameColumnCaption" valign="top" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" style="height: 19px;">11:00</td>
    </tr>
```

with additional div and table-layout: fixed as suggested:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Q4f.jpg)

```
    <tr>
      <td class="NameColumnCaption" valign="top" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" style="height: 19px;">11:00</td>
      <td class="weekdetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" rowspan="8" colspan="10" style="cursor:pointer" ondblclick="modifyMeeting(&quot;212&amp;dispUser=Janice%20Elland&amp;globObjID=&quot;, 9);" onclick="detailview(&quot;oneweek.asp?Q=Janice%20Elland&amp;D=-5&quot;);hN(33);" onmousemove="sN(33)" onmouseout="hN(33)">
        <div style="height: 100%; min-height: 70px;">
          <table width="100%" id="tbl" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed;border:1px solid #404040;" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="white">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="5" bgcolor="#99ccff" style="height: 19px;"><img src="b1.gif" width="2px" height="10px" border="0"></td>
                <td class="WeekDetails" valign="top" style="height: 19px;">
                  <font color="#0000cc">11:15-15:15</font><br>
                  <font color="#000000">Supplier Meeting</font> (Lancashire)Janice Elland<br>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="WeekDetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" colspan="10" onmousemove="sN(0)" onmouseout="hN(0)" onclick="Meeting2(&quot;&amp;D=-3&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;Janice%20Elland&quot;);" style="height: 19px;"></td>
      <td valign="top" class="WeekDetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" colspan="10" onmousemove="sN(0)" onmouseout="hN(0)" onclick="Meeting2(&quot;&amp;D=-2&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;Janice%20Elland&quot;);" style="height: 19px;"></td>
      <td valign="top" class="WeekDetails" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" colspan="10" onmousemove="sN(0)" onmouseout="hN(0)" onclick="Meeting2(&quot;&amp;D=-1&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;Janice%20Elland&quot;);" style="height: 19px;"></td>
      <td class="NameColumnCaption" valign="top" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" style="height: 19px;">11:00</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2

I made a new table because the fiddle provided by OP was too cluttered. Fortunately, it illustrated what the problem was. The nested tables did not expand the full height of the `rowspanned td`, so a `td with rowspan="8"` had a  table within that was only 2 rows high instead of 8 rows.

The most important things to know is this:

(For this example the `td` that has the nested table is: `.parent`)

- Apply `min-height: 100%` and `min-width: 100%;` to `.parent`.
- Comment out the `td` under the `.parent`(i.e. `td` in the same column) to the total of `.parent`'s `rowspan`- 1

  - ex. `<td class="parent" rowspan="5"...>`
  - `.parent` is in the first column / third row.
  - comment out the next 4 `td` in:

    1. first column / forth row
    2. first column / fifth row
    3. first column / sixth row
    4. first column / seventh row
- When you construct the nested table, you:

  - make as many `<tr>`s as the `.parent`'s `rowspan`
  - each `<tr>` should have an equal amount of columns
  - don't have to bother with `tbody`

The following demo is annotated with comments designating what's required to get the desired effect. I use the term *required* loosely, because you may have to adjust certain measurements of course (i.e. padding, width, etc.)

https://plnkr.co/edit/u6CpPDDF3hMC5JI1S5BY?p=preview

### Update 1

Since this concerns a table inside another table try:

`<table style="table-layout: fixed; display: inline-table"....>`

Use

- .css file or `<style>` block

  - `table {table-layout: fixed;}`

OR

- inline

  - `<table style="table-layout: fixed; ....>`

You'll probably need to append a div inside a cell and increase it's height in order to increase the table's height.

```
<td>
 <div style="height: 100%; min-height: 70px;">
      "Cell Content"
 </div>
 </td>
```

If your tables are generated and you can't modify the HTML before it's loaded (i.e. editing the code). It is possible to do so programmatically, let me know if you do and I'll help with that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it didn't change much:

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? Wait.. try using: `table style="table-layout: fixed; display: inline-table`

Comment: adding display: inline-table didn't help either. I created a fiddle

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I need some more time to look into this and if your solution works. I will let you know as soon as I know.

Comment: Your'e very welcome, sir. Sure there's no deadline (which is why this isn't work ;-)),